# Decoupling system of differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, linear-algebra, algebraic-manipulation

Here I have one task and it is preparation for small exam. I solved it by hand for first case 1), but I need to check it in $Mathematica$ and to try to implement it for both cases 1) and 2) automatically. After decoupling I am looking for solutions of the decoupled system and how to get them and come back to the source variables because I need solutions of them?

System of two differential equations of 4th order and I need to transform them in 1) equivalent system of 4 equations of second order with appropriate substitutions and 2) 8 equations of first order. How to do that in Mathematica automatically, in one case 4 equations second order maximum and in another case 8 equations of first order maximum? Example is with known constants a and b. I know that I must use some substitutions to reduce the system.

Firstly can be helpful homogenous solution when g1[x] and g2[x] are equal to zero.

first eq

```
  g1[x]==a1*X1[x] + a2*X2[x] + a3*Derivative[2][X1][x] - 
  a4*Derivative[2][X2][x] + a5*Derivative[4][X1][x]
```

second eq

```
  g2[x]==b2*X1[x] + b1*X2[x] - b4*Derivative[2][X1][x] + 
  b3*Derivative[2][X2][x] + b5*Derivative[4][X2][x]
```

1)  4 equations with adopted substitutions of second order differential equations.

2)  8 equations of first order

I did a) by hand in the form

$(\text{x1}=\text{X1}(x)) (\text{x3}=\text{X2}(x)) \left(\text{x2}=\text{X1}''(x)\right) \left(\text{x4}=\text{X2}''(x)\right) $

$ X(x)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \text{x1}(x) \\
 \text{x2}(x) \\
 \text{x3}(x) \\
 \text{x4}(x) \\
\end{array}
\right) $   $, A=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -\frac{\text{a3}}{\text{a1}} & -\frac{\text{a2}}{\text{a1}} & -\frac{\text{a5}}{\text{a1}} & -\frac{\text{a4}}{\text{a1}} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 -\frac{\text{b5}}{\text{b1}} & -\frac{\text{b4}}{\text{b1}} & -\frac{\text{b3}}{\text{b1}} & -\frac{\text{b2}}{\text{b1}} \\
\end{array}
\right)$ $, B=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 \frac{\text{g1}(x)}{\text{a1}} \\
 0 \\
 \frac{\text{g2}(x)}{\text{b1}} \\
\end{array}
\right)$ $$ X''(x)=A X(x)+B$$

Comment: @Nasser thank you, it is corrected now. It is not partial, just of one variable

Comment: @Naser it can e helpful also homogenous solution firstly when the functions g1 and g2 are equal to zero

Comment: @I didn't speak about standard state space formulation. I need solutions of system of differential equations and how to transform it in 4 second order

Answer (score 4):

I am a little confused by your terms and what you have shown. But in case it helps, one way to obtain the state space matrix is to use `StateSpaceModel` as follows

```
eq1 = g1[x] == 
   a1*X1[x] + a2*X2[x] + a3*Derivative[2][X1][x] - 
    a4*Derivative[2][X2][x] + a5*Derivative[4][X1][x];

eq2 = g2[x] == 
   b2*X1[x] + b1*X2[x] - b4*Derivative[2][X1][x] + 
    b3*Derivative[2][X2][x] + b5*Derivative[4][X2][x];

StateSpaceModel[{eq1, 
  eq2}, {{X1'[x], 0}, {X1[x], 0}, {X2'[x], 0}, {X2[x], 0}}, {{g1[x], 
   0}, {g2[x], 0}}, {X1[x], X2[x]}, x]
```

Which gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We see there are 8 state variables as expected.

You find more information on the above command here http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StateSpaceModel.html

Comment: I need 4 second order and solutions.

Comment: what I can do with this?

Comment: vote down sorry, you didnt understand

Comment: @naser what does two separated columns and rows represent? what is a solution of this matrix of differential equations, how to reform now the system in 8 diff equations

Comment: my full description of the problem is here, maybe you can understand what actually I need. Thank you for your attention and try.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287762/neglecting-solutions-and-reforming-the-system-of-differential-equations-with-red